# display only first 10 records from array using c# jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

**Index.aspx**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {

                $.each(msg.d, function (index, value) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(value.Email);
                });


            }
        })
        return false;
    });
```

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]

        public static IEnumerable<TemperatureEntity> GetData()
        {
         //return array data
```

> I have traverse through array and want to display it in tabular format on html like email,phonenumber.
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Return 10 elements from your web method ?

Comment: What is the issue? You have asked 488 previous question poor question

Comment: Another thing to point out you have almost 4k points and you still doesn't know how to ask proper question.

Comment: yes I'm working on that sorry for it.

Comment: thanks actually i'm trying to do similar with my business logic sorry for silly questions , i would not able to write down proper questions as actual   implementation is complex , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it exaclty on the client side then check the [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) jQuery function

You should modify your code as following:

```
var slicedData = msg.d.slice(0, 10);
$.each(slicedData, function (index, value) {
                    var html = $('#myDiv').html();
                    html += value.Email;
                    html += value.PhoneNumber;
                    $('#myDiv').html(html + '<br />');
                });
```

But if you can modify the resulting array on the server side - do it on server side with `Linq` method `Take(10)`;

Comment: `$('#myDiv').html(value.Email);` it oveerrides 1st value and display only last. only one value it prints.
how to print all 10 values in table format ?

Comment: @Neo I have no idea what markup do you have and what does mean "table format". Anyway it is not related to problem of displaying only first 10 values.

Comment: thanks actually i'm trying to do similar with my business logic sorry for silly questions , i would not able to write down proper questions as actual   implementation is complex , thanks a lot